# Show that a vector field is not conservative (example)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{R^2}\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\}$ and $$\vec{F}(x,y)=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\vec{i}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\vec{j}$$ To show that the vector field $F$ is **not** conservative $$\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{F}=0\,\vec{i}+0\,\vec{j}+\bigg(\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\bigg)\vec{k}=\vec{0}$$ which indicates that it is conservative(?). Alternatively, the scalar function

$$f(x,y)=-\arctan\bigg(\frac{x}{y}\bigg)$$ is the potential function of the field $F$. If $$\int_C\vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}\neq f\big(x(\beta),y(\beta)\big)-f\big(x(\alpha),y(\alpha)\big)$$ $\big($where $r(t)$ is the parametrization of an arbitrary curve $c$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are its starting and end point respectively$\big)$

then the fundumental theorem for line integrals is not satisfied and thus $F$ is not conservative.
I tried using $r(t)=t\vec{i}+t\vec{j}, \space t\in[\alpha,\beta]$, but it didn't work.

What curve would be a better choice for $C$ and what's the deal with $\mathrm{rot}\,F$ being zero?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Omega=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,0\}$?  Did you want to say $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\big\{(0,0)\big\}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.

Comment: The point of this exercise is to show that a curl-less vector field is not necessarily conservative.  So, no, the curl being zero doesn't mean you have a conservative vector field.

Comment: but how can the not-conservative part be shown?

Comment: This is what you need to show: $$\int_c\vec{F}\cdot\text{d}\vec{r}\neq f\big(x(\beta),y(\beta)\big)-f\big(x(\alpha),y(\beta)\big)\,,$$ for some path $c$.  One side is always $0$, but the other may be nonzero, depending on $c$.

Comment: Is the left side $0$ for every $c$?

Comment: Yes.  Did you solve the problem now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most important "functions" in classical analysis is the ${\rm arg}$ function, giving the polar angle of a point $(x,y)$, resp., of $z=x+iy$,  in the punctured plane "up to an additive constant $2k\pi$". Locally, i.e., in suitable neighborhoods of points $(x_0,y_0)\in\dot{\mathbb R}^2$ this function has well-defined real representants. E.g., in the half plane $x>0$ we may choose the representant $$\phi(x,y):=\arctan{y\over x}\ .$$
Now this ${\rm arg}$ "function" has a well-defined gradient
$$\nabla{\rm arg}(x,y)=\left({-y\over x^2+y^2},{x\over x^2+y^2}\right)\qquad\bigl((x,y)\ne(0,0)\bigr)\ .$$It turns out that your ${\bf F}$ is nothing else but $\nabla{\rm arg}$. Since, locally,  ${\rm arg}$ is represented by smooth functions $(x,y)\mapsto\phi(x,y)$ it follows that ${\rm curl}\,{\bf F}\equiv0$.

But it is **impossible** to concatenate the local polar angles $\phi(x,y)$ to one single real-valued polar angle function $\phi:\>\dot{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. This then implies that the given ${\bf F}$ is **not** conservative. A definitive proof of this fact comes from computing $\int_\gamma {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf z}$ along the unit circle $\gamma$. Along this circle the argument increases continuously by $2\pi$, hence the value of this integral is $2\pi\ne0$.

Answer (score 5):

The assertion that $\nabla \times {\bf F} = {\bf 0}$ is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one. (Note that this condition implicitly uses the unstated realization of $\Bbb R^2$ as the $xy$-plane in $\Bbb R^3$.) As Batominovski points out in the comments, this is the key lesson of the problem.

**Hint** Now, the scalar function $f(x, y) = -\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$ is not a potential for $\bf F$---for the simple reason that $f$ is not defined on all of the domain of $\bf F$ (it isn't defined anywhere on the $x$-axis). On the other hand, it *is* a potential for the restriction ${\bf F}|_R$ of $\bf F$ to the right half-plane $R$, so that restriction is conservative, and hence any counterexample cannot use curves wholly contained within $R$.

It is, by the way, sufficient to think about closed curves $C$, since any two curves with the same endpoints form a closed loop. Then for any such curve and conservative vector field $\bf G$, your formula gives $\int_C {\bf G} \cdot d{\bf s} = 0$.

So: What is a closed curve---again not contained in $R$---along which it is easy to evaluate $\int_C {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf s}$ directly? If we can find a $C$ for which the integral is nonzero, the contrapositive of the previous observation gives that $\bf F$ is not conservative.

> **Additional hint** One such curve is the unit circle, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, on which ${\bf F} = -y {\bf i} + x {\bf j}$.

Comment: Can a quick explanation be that, since there's no function with the same domain as $\vec{F}$ whose gradient is $\vec{F}$,$\vec{F}$ is not conservative?

Comment: That's a *definition* of conservative, and so that statement is certainly true here.

Answer (score -1):

If a differentiable field $\vec{F}(x,y)=F_1(x,y)\vec{i}+F_2(x,y)\vec{j}$ is conservative then you must have $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}$ in every point of the domain. You can easily check that your field doesn't have this property.

Comment: Is this a sufficient condition? Is it not equivalent to $rotF=\vec{0}$ ?

Comment: It's a necessary condition for a field to be conservative, hence if a field doesn't have that property then it can't be conservative. But if you had to prove that a vector field is conservative then no, that's not a sufficient condition. However it is sufficient if the domain of the field is convex or at least star shaped.

Comment: The vector field *does* have this property---in fact, this property is equivalent to the vanishing of the coefficient of $\bf k$ that OP observed in their question.

Comment: You are right, it has that property. I got confused.